# Load vtkDICOMReader from vtkImageData

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vtk, itk

In [vtkDICOMReader](http://dgobbi.github.io/vtk-dicom/doc/api/classvtk_d_i_c_o_m_reader.html) documentation exist methods that get data from DICOM files. There is any method to push data into **vtkDICOMReader** from another **vtkImageData**, for instance **vtkImageExtractComponents** (**vtkImageExtractComponents::GetImageDataInput**) ?

Comment: The purpose of the reader is to read file from disk and to make data available as a VTK  object. If your data is already available as a vtkImageData, what are you trying to achieve by `pushing data into` the reader ?

Comment: and please specify when you crosspost from another website ... https://discourse.vtk.org/t/vtkimageextractcomponents-to-vtkdicomreader/3682

Comment: Of course, I have written on other forum too because I really needed a solution. Thank you for your implication.

Comment: Problem with cross posting (and no link) is that people can take on their own time to help you about an already answered question, that's frustrating. That said, you can answer yourself here to mark the post as resolved

Comment: You had right in a way, and you didn't in other way. Depending of how is your mind set. The positive way to ask the same question on two forums is that you can get two or more ideas instead of one. Anyway, I'll try to write here that answer.